# Remove 'onclick' command from a child of a div

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a [website](http://www.rate-me-now.com) where I have a main `div`. I wanted all of the `div`'s page-area to act as a link (clicking on it will cause a submitting of a form and moving to another page) so I added to that `div` the attribute:

```
<div class="box1" onclick="javascript:document.forms['womenForm'].submit();" ...>
```

Everything in this area shuold link to the next page **apart from** an HTML selection that is inside this div, but should be clickable without moving to the next page.

How can I cause this to happen? I tried to wrap the selected element with a div, giving it `href=""` or `onclick=""` but still the form is submitted.

Can anybody resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to stop the bubbling of the event up the hierarchy ...

using the onclick attribute you can do this with

`onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();return false;"` on the select element.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol is superfluous in your code because you're using the "onclick" attribute.

I suggest moving away from inline JavaScript and venturing into the more acceptable [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/) world.

Anyway, what you want to do is check that the event was not fired on a `<select>` element. With unobtrusive JS that would go something like this:

```
someElement.onclick = function(e) {
    var target = e ? e.target : event.srcElement;
    if (!/option|select/i.test(target.nodeName)) {
        // do stuff.
    }
};
```

Comment: is this the simplest way? can't I remove from a child element the attribute of his upper perents as part of the HTML definition?